# Transmit the binary diff(delta) of a file over http and merge the diff on the server

Tags: http, rsync, delta

Basically i need to find out the binary diff of a file (client and server) and then transmit the diff(delta) over HTTP and then merge the diff(delta) to the file.
Is there any tool for this?
One more requirement is that it should work on all environments.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you might be looking for.

Options:-
[1].
**zsync** sends data using delta transfer algorithm (same is used in rsync tool) but over http
read more about zsync and try using it straight away
everything about zsync here :-

http://zsync.moria.org.uk/

[2]. Syncrify. Known tool for rsync over http. Though I have not used it. I doubt this is free tool.
  http://web.synametrics.com/Syncrify.htm

[3]. Also , check csync http://www.csync.org/ .
  I haven't used this tool. But, got it's reference in this post:-
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8578192/1617067

**[EDIT]**
you can find library for remote delta-tranfer algorithm used in rsync here:-
http://librsync.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.But is there any tools which will give me the handle of the delta so that i can transmit it over http and then the tool on the server side will merge the delta.